# How to send data to router link body

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am using router link, i want to pass some data to the router body.

So i have code in HTML file as below

`routerLink="/detailReports/{{report.id}}` - here i want to pass the report name as well to the router data.

So that when i try to retrieve something from ActivatedRouteSnapshot like below i can get the data that i have passed from the routerlink.

```
private getActivatedComponent(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
    if (snapshot.firstChild) {
      return this.getActivatedComponent(snapshot.firstChild);
    }
    return snapshot;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send more information in your request, I recommend you to use query params. You can send more info like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/users']"
   [queryParams]="{ filter: 'new' }"
   queryParamsHandling="merge">
  Users
</a>
```

You can checkout here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-query-parameters

Comment: i am getting the value of query parameter like an array
{
n
a
m
e
}
 everything in different line and not in same line and also it is being passed in the URL as well. I don't want the query parameters to be there in the URL

Comment: If you don't want the parameters be in the URL you have two options, first you have to use a service that handle the info between components. Another option in that the component that you are using became parent-child so in that way you can pass the info form the parent to son directly, and son to parent with events.

Comment: but why is the query params coming like an array? How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure query params are comming like an array? Can you show how do you get the query params?